# What does the asterisk and period do in find -name "*.mp3"?

Tags: command-line, find

In `find -name "*.mp3"`, there is an asterisk before the .mp3. Doesn't the `*` match the character before it any number of times? But there is nothing in front of the asterisk, so what does the `*` do? Or is it because the `find` command does not use regular expressions? So, is the `.` in .mp3 a regular expression character or does `find` just interprets it as a period to match?

Comment: The [`find` man page's description of `-name`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) points to [`fnmatch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html) which points to [`glob`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) which has a complete description in the first couple sentences and wasn't hard to look up.

Comment: Wow. First time I see someone expecting globbing to work like regexp. It's more often to see people being confused because regexp does not behave like glob.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### The `-name` predicate takes a [glob](https://foldoc.org/glob), not a regular expression.

In a regular expression, `*` would match zero or more of the preceding item. But since this is a glob, it matches zero or more of any character. That is, `*` in a glob means the same thing as `.*` in a regular expression.

In a regular expression, `.` would match exactly one of any character. But since this is a glob, it is not treated specially, and simply matches a literal `.` character. That is, `.` in a glob means the same thing as `\.` or `[.]` in a regular expression.

If you did want to match a single occurrence of any character in a glob, you would use `?`. In a glob, `?` means the same thing as `.` in a regular expression. This is quite different from `?` in a regular expression, which matches zero or one of the preceding item (i.e., makes the preceding item optional).

The only syntax that's *mostly* the same in both globs and regular expressions is character classes enclosed in `[` `]`. For example, `[aeiou]` matches any character that is either `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, or `u`. If you write a `[` `]`-delimited character class that works in most regex dialects, it's likely to be a character class with the same meaning when used in a glob, too.

---

Other than as the operand to `find`'s `-name` and `-iname` predicates, another place where globs are widely used is by your shell. Unquoted globbing metacharacters are expanded by your shell automatically into a list of separate arguments corresponding to the filenames they match.

This is why it's important to quote such a pattern when passing it to `find`. If you don't, your shell will try to expand it. If your shell does expand it, `find` won't see the pattern itself, but instead the result of its expansion. This is undesirable and often confusing.

Note that your shell (probably bash, but this is true of Unix-style shells in general) will not, *as its default behavior*, expand `?` or `*` to match a leading dot in a filename. For example, unless you've told it to behave otherwise, your shell expands `?` to the filenames in the current directory that are one character long, *other than `.`* , even though a `.` entry is always present. And it expands `*` to the filenames in the current directory that don't start with `.`. (In bash, `shopt -s dotglob` would change this for the shell instance you run it in, and `shopt -u dotglob` would restore the default behavior.) It is only leading dots that are special, not other dots.

This differs from the behavior of `find`'s `-name` and `-iname` predicates, where `?` and `*` are always permitted to match a leading `.`.

Comment: This answer could probably be improved by adding a glob/regex/meaning table.

Comment: Notice that, by default, on a regular expression, using `.*` doesn't match newlines. If a file has a newline somewhere in the name (if possible), using `.*` wouldn't match it. However, using `(\s|.)*` is enough to match newlines, or `[^\0]*`.

Answer (score 1):

The Asterisk (commonly known as the "Wildcard Operator") says that `find` should return *all* files with the `.mp3` extension.

Answer (score -9):

Because you use double quotes, `bash` tries to expand the `"*.mp3"` glob.

If there are some `*.mp3` files in the current directory, their names will **replace** the glob.

To demonstrate, put an `echo` at the beginning of the line, e.g. `echo find ...`.

If you use single quotes (`'`), glob expansion is not performed.

Use "`'*.mp3'`" instead of "`"*.mp3"`".

Comment: Bash does *not* try to expand a glob in `"*.mp3"`. Although double quotes provide a weaker form of quoting than single quotes, [globbing characters (`?`, `*`, and `[`) are not among the characters still treated specially in double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes). Double quotes and single quotes both prevent the shell from expanding a glob. Running your demonstration confirms this. (Or you can use the simpler command `echo "*"`.)